# Print message from launch file

Tags: roslaunch

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am wondering if there is any way to print message from launch file. For example, I am calling a node from launch file and I do not want the user to terminate this process. Hence I simply want to print following:

```
Please keep this running in a separate tab.
```

Any workaround to achieve it? Thank you very much. Please note that I am using Python 2.7 in ROS Indigo on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS PC.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/276176/print-message-from-launch-file/) by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1744 on 2017-11-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

rostopic echo:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<launch>
  <arg name="msg" default="Please keep this running in a separate tab." />
  <node name="pub_text" pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic"
     args="pub /msg std_msgs/String '$(arg msg)'"
     output="screen" />
  <node name="print_text" pkg="rostopic" type="rostopic"
     args="echo /msg" output="screen" />
```

yields:

```
data: Please keep this running in a separate tab.
```

Though maybe the `data:` is undesirable

Adding a -p to the echo yields:

```
%time,field.data
1510939080429253101,Please keep this running in a separate tab.
```

---

Originally posted by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) with karma: 8729 on 2017-11-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I don't think it's possible to print text directly form the roslaunch xml (w/o passing it into a node as a param / arg).

**Best solution** would be to put

```
print("Please keep this running in a separate tab.")
```

**in your node script.**

---

In your *.launch script, if you set the [node's output attribute to "screen"](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node), the message will be printed to the terminal window.

```
<node name="PrintToScreenNode_1" pkg="my_package" type="print_to_screen.py" output="screen"/>
```

---

Note: You can also start your nodes in their own separate terminal windows using the [launch-prefix attribute](http://wiki.ros.org/roslaunch/XML/node).

```
<node name="PrintToScreenNode_2" pkg="my_package" type="print_to_screen.py" output="screen" launch-prefix="xterm -e"/>
```

---

EDIT:

Here's an example script that just prints to the terminal:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

'''
# Name: print_to_screen.py
# Author: Joseph Coombe
'''

# Uncomment lines 10, 13, 15 if you're running this node in its own separate
# terminal window. Otherwise the script will immediately exit and its terminal window will close.
#import rospy

def main():
    #rospy.init_node('print_to_screen', anonymous=True)
    print("Please keep this running in a separate tab.")
    #rospy.spin()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

You'll want to un-comment the `rospy` lines if you're launching this script in its own terminal (by using the launch-prefix attribute in your *.launch file). Otherwise, it'll immediately exit and close its terminal window (and as a result nobody will see the message).

---

Originally posted by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) with karma: 697 on 2017-11-17

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ravijoshi](https://answers.ros.org/users/25207/ravijoshi/) on 2017-11-17**:
Thank you very much. I want to know, if it is possible to create `print_to_screen.py` with only following content and nothing else `print("Please keep this running in a separate tab.")`

**Comment by [josephcoombe](https://answers.ros.org/users/31943/josephcoombe/) on 2017-11-17**:
@Ravi Joshi Yes. I've edited my answer with a simple example.

**Comment by [hbaqueiro](https://answers.ros.org/users/37094/hbaqueiro/) on 2018-11-08**:
What about printing a value from inside the launch file, say an arg or param value? How can the python script access them and print?